# App references non-public selectors in Payload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After validate the app this message appears.

```
"iTunes Store operation failed.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.../App: setStreamError:, setStreamStatus:"
```

Do you have any ideas what's means? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The automatic check iTunes Store performs detected your app is using the selectors `setStreamError:` and `setStreamStatus:`, that are non-public.

If you are using a private API, your app will be rejected (and this is the reason).

If you have chosen your method names and they are the same as some Apple private API, I suggest you change them and resubmit.

Comment: i already made a search in the project and any result for the both names method (setStreamError: and setStreamStatus:). How can find out where this error comes ?

Comment: Are you using any third party library? They might be referencing those selectors too.

Comment: i checked allover, nothing with those name. i cleaned the project so just public frameworks.

Comment: Is it due to facebook plugin which we have used? coz before that, it was able to upload!

Comment: I wouldn't think so, since lots of apps use that framework.